# Using a cursor loader with BLOB data

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I asked a similar question a month ago but didn't really get an answer that helped, so I wanted to see if I could better phrase the question.

I am working with an app that stores BLOB data in a database. The data is a picture image, very small (less then 2KB). I decided to dave them directly into the database because of the size.

I am still learning about programming, and I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but here is my issue. I have a lot of text fields in my database, and I pull information from them using this method:

```
private void fillData() {

    // Pulls the fields from the database and assigns them to the columns

    String[] from = new String[] { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM,
            BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE };

    // The label for each textview
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label, R.id.pName, R.id.pDate };

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bm_row, null, from,
            to, 0);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My class implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks and the accompanying methods are as follows:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    // Remove to show all records - This sets up the list to filter based on
    // items returned
    String mSelection = BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_BORROW_FLAG + "=?";

    // SQL request for only returned items to be shown
    String[] selectionArgs = { "Borrowed" }; // The actual argument

    String[] projection = { BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ID,
            BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM, BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_NAME,
            BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_DATE };
    // mSelection & selectionArgs can be removed and set to null to display
    // all records
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
            BorrowMeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, mSelection,
            selectionArgs, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

When I attempt to add the column that has the blob data in it - I get an error saying I cannot convert a blob to a string:

```
06-30 15:13:36.152: E/AndroidRuntime(842): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
```

I know this is because I'm attempting to read it as a string like everything else, but I'm at a loss for how to grab it properly using this method. I'm loading the data into rows of a listactivity.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I've not found a lot online dealing with cursor loader and listview.

Thanks

Update - I created a new bindview for the simple cursor adaptor but i still get the following error message:

```
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:           unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at  android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:150)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:250)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-02 20:42:53.350: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the code I have used for my view binder:

```
public class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder {

@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int viewId = view.getId();

    Log.i("ViewBinder: view", Integer.toString(viewId));
    Log.i("ViewBinder: name",cursor.getString(2));
    Log.i("ViewBinder: email",cursor.getString(3));
    Log.i("ViewBinder: photo",cursor.getBlob(4)==null?"NO Photo":"Has photo");

    switch(viewId){

    case R.id.pic_of_item:

        ImageView storedItem = (ImageView) view;

        byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);

        // If the blob is null then pull it from database
        if (blob != null){

            // Decode the bitmap from the blob
            storedItem.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length));

            Log.i("RETURN TRUE BLOB",cursor.getString(3));

        } else {

            // If nothing is found use the camera icon from drawable 
            storedItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.take_camera_small);

            Log.i("RETURN TRUE NO BLOB",cursor.getString(3));

            return true;
        }

    }

    Log.i("RETURN FALSE",cursor.getString(3));

    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` uses `cursor.getString` to retrieve the value from the database, as seen in [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java). For images, it assume the String value it retrieved is the integer that points to a particular image resource (i.e., calls `v.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(value))`). Hence, `SimpleCursorAdapter` has no understanding of how to deal with blob data and you'll need to use your own `CursorAdapter` class that does the proper conversion from blob to `Bitmap` to set onto your `ImageView`, probably using something like the following code in your `bindView`:

```
ImageView imageView = // get your ImageView
byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I was able to create my own viewbinder using the steps from the article [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951871/sqlite-blob-column-to-simplecursoradapter-with-viewbinder) but I still get an error message about String to Blob

Comment: @Vince - so you've set up a `ViewBinder` that has a switch looking for `BorrowMeTable.COLUMN_ITEM`? `getString` is only called within `bindView` if your `ViewBinder` returns `false`. Have you confirmed (via `Log` statements or debugging) that your `ViewBinder` is handling the image and returning `true`?

Comment: I have confirmed via log statements that it returns tru and then false just after. I have posted my View Binder code above

Comment: Thanks again for any help you can provide - I'm stil new and trying to get the hang of this.

Comment: @Vince - it looks like you are only returning `true` when `blob==null` (your `else` statement) - move that `return true;` statement out of the `else` statement so that both paths return `true`.